# Find in array type field Doctrine and Mysql

Tags: mysql, arrays, symfony, doctrine

I created a field "array" on the mysql DB, following this response: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34127782/8049247)

when persist the data look this:

[image: db table record]

```
{i:0;s:4:"3410";i:1;s:4:"3415";i:2;s:4:"3459";i:3;s:4:"3460";i:4;s:4:"3492";}
```

But don't find in sql query, I tried some things, but I still can not get it

```
SELECT  *
FROM classified_zones cz
WHERE cz.locations_ids IN ( 3492 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build dynamically a doctrine query similar to:

```
$qb->select('cz')
   ->from('myBundle:ClassifiedZones', 'cz')
   ->where('cz.locationsIds LIKE :id')
   ->setParameter('id', '%:'.strlen($id).':"' . $id . '"%' );
```

The final sql query should be similar to Łukasz's response.

Comment: Helped! I used this snnipet.

Answer (score 1):

Following query should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM classified_zones cz
WHERE cz.locations_ids LIKE '%s:4:"3492";%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use "unfamiliar formats", MySQL supports a native JSON data type.

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains

For example:

locations_ids = "[1,2,3,3492]"

```
SELECT cz.* FROM classified_zones cz WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(cz.locations_ids, 3492)
```